# Delete ' of a list in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm making a script that deletes all the numbers from a list that are smaller than 6.4, but in my list numbers are strings (`'9.4'`). I want to delete the `'` in all the numbers of the list so I can make an `if` command.

```
import csv
import operator
import re

x = 6.4

ss = open("APUESTAS.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(ss,delimiter=";")

apuesta_perdedora = []

for row in csv_f:
    pne = row[1]
    apuesta_perdedora.append(row[2])


for item in apuesta_perdedora:
    if int(item) < x:
        apuesta_perdedora.remove(item)


print(list_2)
ss.close()
```

Comment: *"Delete the `'`"* doesn't make sense. You want to *convert the strings to numbers*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are reading from a file you need to convert the numbers from string to float before appending them to the list.

Change `apuesta_perdedora.append(row[2])` to `apuesta_perdedora.append(float(row[2]))`.

You also have an issue with

```
for item in apuesta_perdedora:
    if int(item) < x:
        apuesta_perdedora.remove(item)
```

It is generally a bad idea to delete items from a list while iterating over the same list. You can use list comprehension instead. Note the `>` sign (instead of deleting the unwanted values we keep those we want) :

```
apuesta_perdedora = [num for num in apuesta_perdedora if num > x]
```

or iterate over a copy of the list:

```
for item in apuesta_perdedora[:]:
    if item < x:
        apuesta_perdedora.remove(item)
```

Comment: a classic, but you got all the errors covered & 2 fixes proposal so good one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a list while you are looping over it. Make a new list, and then use it to overwrite the old list when the loop is done:

```
new = []
for item in apuesta_perdedora:
    if float(item) >= x:
        new.append(item)
apuesta_perdedora = new # overwrite old list with new list
```